# Problema con sumar en codigo ascii

Tags: c++, encriptación

Tengo un problema pues al sumar en el codigo ascii un valor para que al final me salga encriptado, no me encripta correctamente, así:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


    
  //  char cont[10];
   int x;
    typedef char cadenaCaracteres [50]; //Definimos el tipo cadenaCaracteres
    cadenaCaracteres arrayCadenas[5]; //Creamos un vector de cadenas
        cadenaCaracteres arraydos[5]; //Creamos un vector de cadenas
    char clave[50];
    char nombre[50];
    int num, y=0;
  int numero=0;
  int s=3;
int cont=0;

  
    
int main()
{
    
volver:
cout<<"Digite un numero de acuerdo a lo que desea realizar\n";
cout<<"1. Ingresar contrasena de un usuario\n";
cout<<"2. Visualizar los usuarios y contrasenas registradas\n";
cin>> num; 
system("cls");
switch(num){
```

Aqui se pide los valores nombre y contraseña a encriptar

```
    case 1:
        cout<<"Cuantas contrasenas desea encriptar \n";
        cin>> numero;
        system("cls");
    for(x=0;x<numero;x++){
        
    cout<< "Ingrese nombre: ";
    cin>> arrayCadenas[x];
    cout<<"Ingrese contrasena: ";
    cin>>arraydos[x];
    
    
     
    
     
    
      if (arraydos[x]!='\0')
      {
       arraydos[x]=s+arraydos[x];
      }
      
    
    


}

system("cls");
    goto volver;
```

Aqui es donde se ven los valores los cuales serian encriptados

```
    case 2:
        
        
    for(x=0;x<numero;x++){
            
     cout<< x;
     cout<<"\t"<<arrayCadenas[x]<<"---->";
    cout<<"La clave es: "<<arraydos[x]<<"\n";
   
}
}
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    goto volver;
    
    
    
}
```

el error se encuentra en la linea que dice :

```
arraydos[x]=s+arraydos[x];
```

el error es: [Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'cadenaCaracteres {aka char [50]}'
agradecería me ayuden a encontrar el error o a entender el por que me sale este mismo, muchisimas gracias

Comment: Para copiar arrays de caracteres se usa `strcpy`, no se pueden asignar asi como lo estas haciendo tu. Ademas, estas en C++, porque no usar `std::string`?

Comment: @Pablochaches Lo que sucede es que mi experiencia en este lenguaje es muy basica, y no comprendo muchas cosas sobre estos metodos, si me pudieras ayudar te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Por mas que me gustaria ayudarte, lo que yo pueda colocar aqui no va a bastar para darte las bases. Primero porque no soy muy bueno explicando, y segundo porque no hay tanto espacio. Lo que si puedo darte son recursos para que investigues. [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/dashboard) es bueno para aprender C++ de forma practica. Ahora, lo que tu estas trabajando mas bien parece C con `cin` y `cout`. El `typedef`, los `char[]` son mas de C que de C++, asi que te puedo recomendar un buen tutorial de C ...

Comment: ... La universidad de Harvard tiene un curso en ciencias de la computacion muy bueno, [lo puedes ver aqui](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLhQjrBD2T381L3iZyDTxRwOBuUt6m1FnW). En las lecturas 1 y 2 se explica de forma magnifica lo que tu necesitas, y si quieres tener una base solida en C, te recomiendo que veas de la 1 a la 5. Si quieres una buena base para la progra en general te recomiendo que lo mires todo. Ya con las bases en C, agarrarle el truco en C++ se te hara muy simple.

Comment: Mucha suerte, y si tienes cualquier duda nos cuentas.